# How to populate SQL options for ModelBuilder parameter from ArcSDE feature class?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, modelbuilder

I am creating a very basic model tool for a class project and I am running into trouble getting the SQL values to populate. I have read the [ArcGIS 10: How to populate SQL options for parameter in tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58591/arcgis-10-how-to-populate-sql-options-for-parameter-in-tool) post. If I need to convert this model into a script tool I can but I was wondering if I can change something in the model before attempting to make it a script. here is a screen shot of the model.[image]
[image]
Basically I just want the user to be able to open the SQL builder and select NAME = "" but the values and fields are not populated I noticed in the other post you can specify to populate from another parameter in the script. Is there anyway to do this in the model if not what would I set as my feature parameter if I created a script. As you may have guessed I am a beginner with python and model builder so I appologize if this is a "dumb question".
here is a screen shot of the layers att table if that helps[image]
[image]

Comment: is name a domain field? if not I think you will have to build your own available value list.

Comment: @Brad Nesom I dont think it is, its just a field of county names would I use the collect values tool to build a available values list?

Comment: Can you include in your question a graphic of the Parameters tab of your model with the NAME field highlighted so we can see its settings, please?  It looks like you may have it set to a data type of SQL Expression rather than Field.

Comment: @PolyGeo good idea Im not in the lab now but I will post in the morning thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have attached a screenshot of my parameters tab it is set as an SQL should it be set to something else I thought since the parameter is a variable from the select tools SQL option.

Comment: If I run the tool then the SQL builder populates but I want the user to be able to build the statement before the tool is run can I load values ex:county names into the query builder manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my [previous questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/51921/how-to-create-drop-down-list-variable-with-modelbuilder) regarding building value list filters in modelbuilder may help.

This will allow the user to choose from a list of available options you have built into the parameter/model.

Comment: funny because I stumbled across your post about 30 minutes ago and it definatley helped I changed the select your AP County to a string variable with the the counties as a value list filter and used the "NAME" = '%Select your AP Counties%' for the SQL query in the select tool. I also did the same for the Aquatic Preserves parameter and it works now. Thanks all for the help I would vote this answer but I cant due to my lowly status.

Comment: *definitely sorry

Comment: @ChrisR you should be able to upvote this answer so perhaps try again

Comment: @PolyGeo at the time I couldn't but now I can and have. Thanks again